# Laravel: conditionally render modal depending of cookie value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display (or not) a newsletter modal according to if a cookie is set or not, for some reason $show_modal always returns false.

Main Page Controller:

```js
public function inicio()
    {

        $show_modal = Modal::checkIfShowModal();

        //dd($show_modal);
        
        return view('inicio.index', compact( 'show_modal'));
    }
```

This is my method for checking if the modal should be shown or not:

Modal.php

```js
public static function checkIfShowModal(){


        $modal = Modal::first();
        
        if($modal->isActive && Cookie::get('cookie_modal_1') !== false)
        {
            //cookie is set, don't show modal
            return false;
        }
        else if($modal->isActive && Cookie::get('cookie_modal_1') == true){
            //cookie isn't set, show modal then
            Cookie::queue( Cookie::make('cookie_modal_1', true, 60*24*7));
            return true;
        }



    }
```

Inside my blade template I use conditional to show render modal

```js
@if($show_modal == true)
    @include('partials/modals/modal_fir')
@endif
```

Modals migration:

```js
Schema::create('modals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->boolean('isActive')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        //FILL MODALS TABLE WITH ONE MODAL
        DB::table('modals')->insert([
            'body' => 'Subscribete a nuestro boletín noticiario, recibe ofertas, noticias, eventos y articulos de nosotros',
            'isActive' => true,
        ]);
```

Any idea why the modal never shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do a strict comparison in `Modal.php`. Try this:

```
public static function checkIfShowModal(){

        $modal = Modal::first();
        //use != instead of !==
        if($modal->isActive && Cookie::get('cookie_modal_1') != false)
        {
            //cookie is set, don't show modal
            return false;
        }
        else if($modal->isActive && Cookie::get('cookie_modal_1') == true){
            //cookie isn't set, show modal then
            Cookie::queue( Cookie::make('cookie_modal_1', true, 60*24*7));
            return true;
        }
       //return default response, true or false (according to preference)
       return true;

    }
```

Comment: after doing that the modal still doesn't show up AND show_modal returns null now instead of true/false, uhmm

Comment: Thank you it works now, I got another question: how can I remove the cookie?

Comment: Ok, use Cookie::forget('cookie_modal_1'); to delete the cookie